# Generic way of Popping & Dismissing View Controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am building an application in which, i have 3 ViewControllers.
Also i have created custom navigation controller.

1. A-ViewController -> This contains 2 buttons, 1st button is for opening B-ViewController & 2nd button is for C-ViewController.
   From 1st button, I am using pushviewcontroller for B-ViewController, means B-ViewController is pushed from A-ViewController.

From 2nd button C-ViewController is presented using presentviewcontroller.

Now on pressing back button in both B & C ViewControllers, I have to use pop view controller in B-ViewController & dismiss in C-ViewController.

As currently i know the pages, but there should be a generic solution.
Is there any way to identify whether current navigation controller is pushed or popped.

As there are some pages which can be pushed or presented, but i dont want to set any bool variable. I need use the support from apple.

```
NSArray *arrViewControllers = [[AppDelegate sharedInstance].navigationController   viewControllers];
NSLog(@"[arrViewControllers count] = %d",[arrViewControllers count]);
```

I am using the above code for fetching the list of view controllers in the stack.
But i am not able to identify whether it is pushed or presented.
Can anybody help me in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for Finding the navigation controller is presented or pushed from previous controller.

```
NSArray *arrViewControllers = [[AppDelegate sharedInstance].navigationController viewControllers];
UIViewController *viewController = [arrViewControllers lastObject];
if (viewController.presentedViewController) 
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
else{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: if (self.isBeingDismissed)
    {
        NSLog(@"present");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"pop");
    }

Answer (score 2):

You can check if your view controller exists in the navigation view controller's stack. Simply check it as

```
if([self.navigationController topViewController] == self){
   //VC is the top most view controller
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}else{
   //You can put some checks here to be dead sure its a modally presented view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];   
}
```

Comment: No actually i am using B view controller to push & present. So how can i identify that the navigation controller is pushed or presented. So that i can write a code for poping & dismissing it.